# Prove $ A \cap B^{c} = \emptyset \iff A \subset B $ given $ A,B \subset U $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

(I have corrected my argument, what is below is my final reasoning made with the help of the best response)

I want to know if I did it right.
First, we assume $ A \cap B^{c} = \emptyset$ to prove $A \cap B^{c} = \emptyset \implies A \subset B $.
\begin{align} 
x \in A &\implies x \notin A^{c} \\ &\implies x \notin A^{c} \wedge x\notin A \cap B^{c} \\ &\implies x \notin A^{c} \wedge (x \notin A \vee x \notin B^{c}) \\ &\implies x\notin B^{c} \\ &\implies x \in B
\end{align}
Next, we assume $ A \subset B $ to prove $ A \subset B \implies A \cap B^{c} = \emptyset $.
$$
A \subset B \iff (x \in A \implies x \in B)
$$
The definition above is just to help the following
\begin{align}
x \in A &\implies x \in B \\ &\implies x\notin B^{c} \\ &\implies x \notin B^{c} \vee x \notin A \iff \neg(x \in A \wedge x \in B^{c}) \iff \neg(x \in A \cap B^{c}) \iff x \notin A \cap B^{c} \iff A \cap B^{c} = \emptyset
\end{align}

Comment: Some cooler notation: `\setminus` gives you the set difference $A \setminus B := A \cap B^C$.

Comment: There is a typo in the last line of the $\Leftarrow$ proof.  You mean to conclude $A \cap B^c= \varnothing, not $A \cap B =\varnothing." Also see the comment in Math_QED's answer below, and @zipirovich's comment below that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first implication is done correctly. Well done! A little remark: How do you justify $x \notin B^c \Rightarrow x \in B$?

For the other implication:

How is $x \notin B^c \Rightarrow x \in B^c = \emptyset$? a valid step?  $x \in \emptyset$ is a statement that is always false, as the empty set contains no elements.

My solution for the $\boxed{\Leftarrow}$ implication would be:

Suppose $A \cap B^c \neq \emptyset$. Then, there is an element $x \in A$ and $x \in B^c$. Because $A \subset B$, it follows that $x \in B$ and $x \in B^c$, which is absurd. This yields the desired contradiction $\quad \triangle$

Comment: To add to your critique of the OP's "$x\notin B^c \Rightarrow x\in B^c=\emptyset$" step: this statement, as written, also says that $B^c=\emptyset$, but that's not necessarily true.

Comment: And if I write $$ \{x \in B^{c}\} = \emptyset $$. Does it make my resolution correct?

Comment: No. This is the same thing as saying that $B^c = \emptyset$, which is not generally true (the intersection is empty though)

Comment: Also, how do you define $B^c$? A complement is usually defined relative to a certain universum (a set where in everything takes place)